# Background image in a UITableView in the Root View of a Split View

Tags: uitableview, ipad

I have an iPad app with a SplitView. On the left (in the RootView) there's a UITableView. How to insert a background image in that UITableView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView Background Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269710/uitableview-background-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how you want this background to behaive.

1. If you want background to stay without movement - put UIImageView "under" your tableview and set backgroundColor for your view with alpha 0.0
2. If you want your background to move with your table use `setBackgroundColor:` and `colorWithPatternImage:`, but it will be titled with size of cells
3. If you want your background to move with table and background will be bigger then 1 cell - follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269710/uitableview-background-image) recommended by KennyTM